# Can I list logins on Conky?

Tags: centos, conky

I would like to list the last 3 logins on conky so it would look something like this

```
username 1/1/2018 12:15 - 12:21  (00:06)
```

The format can very.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a shell script from conky with `execi` followed by the time to wait between reruns:

```
${execi 30 last | awk '
 /^wtmp begins/{ print s[(i+1)%3]"\n"s[(i+2)%3]"\n"s[i]; exit } 
 /^reboot /{ next }
 NF>0{ i=(i+1)%3; s[i]=$0;}'
```

The above, for example, runs the `last` command every 30 seconds, and keeps the last 3 lines seen which do not begin `reboot`, and writes them out when we see a line beginning `wtmp begins`, which marks the end of the output from `last`.